# Cannot retrieve wchar text passed to unicode window

Tags: win32gui

I am creating a unicode window by registering it with WNDCLASSEXW and RegisterClassExW. However I am unable to pass text to it.

In my window procedure, I am unable to recover the text with CREATESTRUCTA or CREATESTRUCTW lpszName member. Only the first letter is seen.

```
HWND myCustomWidgetProcedure(HWND h,UINT m,WPARAM w,LPARAM l)
{
    if(m == WM_CREATE)
    {
      // only first letter is printed
     std::cout << ((CREATESTRUCTA*)l)->lpszName;
     std::wcout <<  ((CREATESTRUCTW*)l)->lpszName;
    }
    return 0;
}

LPCWSTR registerMyCustomWidgetProcedureW()
{
 WNDCLASSEXW wc{};
 wc.cbSize = sizeof(wc);
 wc.lpfnWndProc = myCustomWidgetProcedure;
 wc.lpszClassName = L"myCustomWidgetW";
 return (LPCWSTR)RegisterWindowExW(&wc);
}

HWND createMyCustomWidgetProcedureW(HWND parent)
{
 static auto wndClass = registerMyCustomWidgetProcedureW();
  return CreateWindowExW(0,wndClass, L"Text I want to display",WS_CHILD, 0,0,0,0,parent,0,0,0);
}
```

Comment: Showing the code from your window procedure might be helpful.

Comment: That effect likely stems from wchar in the ASCII range, hence the second byte NUL. Using a special wchar, will then show more letters. As Mark Ransom said, show more code.

Comment: @Joop Eggen I have printed the string using both std::cout and std::wcout with same result. The first two bytes are first letter and null. The rest are garbage Value.

Comment: `wc.lpszClassName = "myCustomWidgetW";` should have given you a compiler warning since you're assigning an ANSI string to a Unicode pointer. Also, your call to `RegisterWindowEx` should be `RegisterWindowExW` since you want to register a Unicode class. (That line should also have generated a compiler warning. Did you disable all warnings by chance?)

Comment: @Raymond Chen As it has to do with my example, it contains those mistakes as it is not a copy paste from my project, but something I typed on my phone to illustrate. I however solved my problem by defining UNICODE. I am using minggw. Any idea why I had to define UNICODE in my translation unit?

Comment: Without UNICODE defined, everything defaults to ANSI. You are probably calling an ANSI function by mistake somewhere. e.g. DefWindowProc.

Comment: @Raymond Chen thats true. I still havent touched DefWindowProc. And Now if I pass ANSI string to CreateWindowEx, it arrives as question marks "????????a". I definately will adjust DefWindowProc. Thank alots.

Comment: @Raymond Chen thank you Sir. I adjusted my procedure to on default, test if IsWindowUnicode and return DefWindowProcW if true and DefWindowProcA otherwise. I also removed UNICODE definition and my code works properly. Thank you Mr. Chen.

Comment: The window procedure should just call DefWindowProcW since it was registered with RegisterClass(Ex)W. Don't use IsWindowUnicode.

Comment: Mr. Chen I  am using both Unicode and Ansi versions as Wc_edit does, but I use one window procedure.

Comment: @Raymond Chen can you kindly advice me why TabCtrl_SetCurSel is not changing the tab I am viewing?

Comment: @Raymond Chen my last problem was another mistake. I SubClassed Tab Control and was handling mouse click to destroy and change tabs. But returned the default tab control behaviour which reselected the tab I was switching from.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem. Even though I explicitly append W to RegisterWindow and CreateWindow, I still had to define UNICODE, which sucks.

EDIT

Thanks to Mr. Raymond Chen, I discovered that I needed to use the right version of DefWindowProc. When I defined UNICODE DefWindowProcW was being called. This led to more problems when I tried to send ANSI strings to the window.

In a nutshell, ensure that you are using the right version of each function. Especially DefWindowProc and CREATESTRUCT.